# I can't find Denoiser in 2.80

Tags: rendering

After rendering my first scene in blender with a lot of noise. i tried searching for the denoiser node in composting. i don't seem to see it anywhere. I use blender 2.80.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The Intel® Open Image Denoise is only available in Blender 2.81 and later as compositor node. In order to use it, enable *Denoising Data* in  *View Layer Properties > Passes*.

[image: Denoising Data]

Switch to the compositor and add the node through *Add > Filter > Denoise*. Connect the *Image* output socket from the *Render Layer* to the *Image* input socket of the *Denoise* node. Use the *Denoising Normal* and *Denoising Albedo* from the *Render Layer* node as input for the *Normal* and *Albedo* sockets of the *Denoise* node.

[image: Intel® Open Image Denoise]

---

The build-in denoiser for Cycles can be found in the *View Layer* tab, when Cycles is enabled as render engine.

[image: Denoiser]

Answer (score 1):

There is no denoiser node in blender 2.80
it is it is availbale from blender 2.81.